# Show default editors in perspective?

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

When open a perspective, i want to show two editors in different  floders.

But i don't know how to open editor in folder.

Anybody can help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Editors cannot be opened in folders; and perspective changes does not affect the list of opened editors. This is a basic constraint of the Eclipse GUI in the 3.x series. It might be possible to create a listener to perspective changes, and register it to the workbench sites, but it is a flaky solution, and in some cases it might not work. If you need to display some information, I suggest opening two views (which views can be used to refer some files from the workspace; and even open them as standard editors in the editor area).

In the Eclipse 4.x series, this constraint is limited, and editors and views are considered as equals wrt positioning.